# How to get the Country code from ip address without using any webservice?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, atg

I am trying to fetch a country code using ip address of the client machine in java. But I see they use web services like geolite... Is there any other way to get country from ip address.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No I think it's not , Geolite maintains it's own database which is updated every first Tuesday of each month . Is there any problem in using Geolite ?

Comment: Yes, you can maintain your own database.

Comment: yes,you can download geolite database and maintain by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Create crawler, which will use some webservice to get full list of ip addresses with its countries, save to file and use it in application. You need to update it from time to time, but I have no other ideas how to transform ip to country without any webservice.

Answer (score 1):

MaxMind Geolite provides the same. you need to get their database, and you need to get their java apis with which you can get the location of a particular ip address.

it is just two lines code,

```
LookupService lookup = new LookupService(file,LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
Location locationServices = lookup.getLocation(ipAddress);
```

Here file is the dat file you get from GeoLite, that is the database for the location and ip map.

[Database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)